# BottomNavigationView back button behavior should work like the Youtube App but crashes

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

Steps to reproduce:

1. Start a new Android project, choose "`BottomNavigationView`":
   [image]
2. Replace MainActivity with this:

   ```
   class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   private var fragmentIds = ArrayList<Int>()

   val fragmentA: FragmentA = FragmentA()
   private val fragmentB = FragmentB()
   private val fragmentC = FragmentC()

   private fun getFragment(fragmentId: Int): Fragment {
       when (fragmentId) {
           R.id.navigation_home -> {
               return fragmentA
           }
           R.id.navigation_dashboard -> {
               return fragmentB
           }
           R.id.navigation_notifications -> {
               return fragmentC
           }
       }
       return fragmentA
   }

   private fun updateView(fragmentId: Int) {
       var exists = false
       fragmentIds
               .filter { it == fragmentId }
               .forEach { exists = true }

       if (exists) {
           fragmentIds.remove(fragmentId)
           showTabWithoutAddingToBackStack(getFragment(fragmentId))
       } else {
           fragmentIds.add(fragmentId)
           showTab(getFragment(fragmentId))
       }
   }

   private val onNavigationItemClicked = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
       when (item.itemId) {
           R.id.navigation_home -> {
               updateView(R.id.navigation_home)
               return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
           }
           R.id.navigation_dashboard -> {
               updateView(R.id.navigation_dashboard)
               return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
           }
           R.id.navigation_notifications -> {
               updateView(R.id.navigation_notifications)
               return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
           }
       }
       false
   }

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
       showTabWithoutAddingToBackStack(fragmentA)

       navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNavigationItemClicked)

   }

   private fun showTab(fragment: Fragment) {
       supportFragmentManager
               .beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.main_container, fragment, fragment::class.java.simpleName)
               .addToBackStack(fragment::class.java.simpleName)
               .commit()
   }

   fun showTabWithoutAddingToBackStack(fragment: Fragment) {
       supportFragmentManager
               .beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.main_container, fragment, fragment::class.java.simpleName)
               .commit()
   }

   fun setBottomTab(id: Int) {
       navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(null)
       navigation.selectedItemId = id
       // currentTab = id
       navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNavigationItemClicked)
   }
   }
   ```
3. Create 3 new classes, FragmentA, FragmentB and FragmentC:

   ```
   class FragmentA : Fragment() {

   override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
       setHasOptionsMenu(true)
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false)
   }

   override fun onResume() {
       super.onResume()
       val act = activity as MainActivity
       act.setBottomTab(R.id.navigation_home)
   }
   }
   ```

with this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment A" />
</LinearLayout>
```

1. Start the app
2. Press "Dashboard"  - Fragment B is shown
3. Press "Notifications" - Fragment C is shown
4. Press "Dashboard" - Fragment B is shown
5. Press "Home"  - Fragment A is shown
6. Press Back button - Fragment B is shown
7. Press Back button - Fragment C should be shown - App Crashes
8. Press Back button - Fragment A should be shown - App is crashed
9. Press Back button - App shuts down. - App is crashed

[Here is a video that demonstrates above steps](http://www.jimclermonts.nl/videos/back-button.MOV)

Stacktrace:

```
12-06 12:58:35.899 25903-25903/com.example.jimclermonts.bottomnavigationview E/InputEventSender: Exception dispatching finished signal.
12-06 12:58:35.900 25903-25903/com.example.jimclermonts.bottomnavigationview E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
12-06 12:58:35.912 25903-25903/com.example.jimclermonts.bottomnavigationview E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.**IllegalStateException: Fragment already added**: FragmentB{3aac1d9 #1 id=0x7f080059 FragmentB}
                                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1882)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executePopOps(BackStackRecord.java:825)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2577)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:851)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:794)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:174)
```

Comment: "I want XXX behavior" Ok, what's wrong with your current implementation?

Comment: @azizbekian I want it to be the same as the Youtube App. But now the back button behavior is not the same.

Comment: @JimClermonts what does exactly "is not the same" mean?

Comment: you means you want to like this one :   https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel

Comment: @saif I'm talking about the bottom navigation, the tabs. It has to be the same as in the youtube app

Comment: @Benjamin i've added the behaviour of youtube, is it clear now what I'm trying to acomplish?

Comment: @JimClermonts see this example : https://segunfamisa.com/posts/bottom-navigation-view-android

Comment: @Saif when pressing back this example app closes. That is the whole problem I'm asking here.

Comment: please share you logcat show me your error log

or put try catch inside your onBackpress method and check your exception

Comment: @Saif added stacktrace and simplified question

Comment: i think you can try to call every time showTab() method for replacing fragment and check your problem comment your showTabWithoutAddingToBackStack method.

Comment: @Saif but then it keeps creating tabs and I have to press back numerous times. It has to function the same way as the youtube app currently does.

Comment: @JimClermonts got the answer?

Comment: Is anybody still facing this problem @BincyBaby?

Comment: App not crashing but back behaviour is different

Answer (score 3):

I have implemented this concept using Bottombar library. I have uploaded to GitHub. Please check and comment here if any issues.

> https://github.com/itvignes09/youtube-like-bttom-menu

Sample output

[image]

Comment: This solution is almost 100% correct. But when going A,B,C,D,E,D,C,B,A and then back 5 times, the last should always be the Home Fragment and then it should shut down.

Comment: I have updated the solution. Please check and let me know

Comment: @ClassA YouTube *could* be using a subclass of `ViewPager` that disables swiping and uses a custom [`PageTransformer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.PageTransformer), overriding the default slide animation. Considering the YouTube app isn't open source, we cannot know for sure.

Comment: How to add child fragment under any tab like you tube and maintain it in back stack? Above example if fine but can you update it with one of child fragment under any tab ? @VigneswaranA

Answer (score 2):

This lets you have the "do not repeat (but reorder) my fragments on the backstack" behavior using a custom backstack (deque):

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private BottomNavigationView navigation;
    // initialize with number of different fragments
    private Deque<Integer> fragmentIds = new ArrayDeque<>(3);

    private FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA();
    private FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB();
    private FragmentC fragmentC = new FragmentC();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fragmentIds.push(R.id.navigation_home);
        showTabWithoutAddingToBackStack(fragmentA);
        navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNavigationItemClicked);
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener onNavigationItemClicked = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            item.setChecked(true);
            int itemId = item.getItemId();
            if (fragmentIds.contains(itemId)) {
                fragmentIds.remove(itemId);
            }
            fragmentIds.push(itemId);
            showTabWithoutAddingToBackStack(getFragment(item.getItemId()));
            return true;
        }
    };

    private Fragment getFragment(int fragmentId) {
        switch (fragmentId) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                return fragmentA;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                return fragmentB;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                return fragmentC;
        }
        return fragmentA;
    }

    void showTabWithoutAddingToBackStack(Fragment fragment) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).commit();
    }

    void setBottomTab(int id) {
        int itemIndex;
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                itemIndex = 1;
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                itemIndex = 2;
                break;
            default:
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                itemIndex = 0;
        }
        navigation.getMenu().getItem(itemIndex).setChecked(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        fragmentIds.pop();
        if (!fragmentIds.isEmpty()) {
            showTabWithoutAddingToBackStack(getFragment(fragmentIds.peek()));
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This implementation is not correct. When pressing rapidly between 2 tabs. I have to press back the same amount of times when going back. The backstack behaviour of the Youtube App is that it remembers the fragment for 1 back press.

Comment: Secondly, When pressing "Home", "Dashboard", "Notifications", "Dashboard", "Home". The back button behaviour should be: "Dashboard", "Notifications", "Home", Close App. Right now this is not the case it memorizes the whole stack.

Comment: Hm, shouldn't you describe this behavior in your question? In your own words and without referring mainly to an example or to "some app out there"? Something like: "Replacing a fragment should add the replaced fragment to the backstack, only if that fragment has not been added to the backstack before or has been popped from the backstack since." Instead we get an error message which I can't reproduce with your code?

Comment: @JimClermonts Please check my new implementation. In case it does not meet your requirements, please disclose them!

Answer (score 0):

I have to change it a bit and got it working, and I have tested wit multiple devices and switching the tabs for more than 100 times in one test run.
Its working fine, change following code,

```
private fun updateView(fragmentId: Int) {
    var exists = false
    fragmentIds
            .filter { it == fragmentId }
            .forEach { exists = true }

    if (exists) {
        fragmentIds.remove(fragmentId)
        showTabWithoutAddingToBackStack(getFragment(fragmentId))
    } else {
        fragmentIds.add(fragmentId)
        showTab(getFragment(fragmentId))
    }
}
```

To this new code,

```
private fun updateView(fragmentId: Int) {
    var exists = false
    fragmentIds
            .filter { it == fragmentId }
            .forEach { exists = true }

    if (exists) {
        showTab(getFragment(fragmentId))
        setBottomTab(fragmentId)
    } else {
        fragmentIds.add(fragmentId)
        showTab(getFragment(fragmentId))
    }
}
```

That's it !!!

Answer (score 0):

Hello Please check this I made this and working fine.
you can check this. https://github.com/sandeshsk/BackStackFragmentRedirectsToHome

Please update if there is any issue.

This is a method which assigns fragment

```
public void addFragment(FragmentManager fragmentManager,
                               Fragment fragment,
                               int containerId,boolean isFromHome){

    fragmentManager.popBackStack(null,FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    if(isFromHome){
        fragmentTransaction.replace(containerId,fragment);
    }else{
        fragmentTransaction.add(new HomeFragment(),"Home");
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("Home");
    }
    fragmentTransaction.replace(containerId,fragment).commit();

}
```

This is your navigation item listener

```
 private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
              if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
                    addFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(), new HomeFragment(), R.id.frame, true);
                }else{
                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                addFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(),new DashboardFragment(),R.id.frame,false);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                addFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(),new NotificationFragment(),R.id.frame,false);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_setting:
                addFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(),new SettingFragment(),R.id.frame,false);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

onBackPressed method

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()>0){
        navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_home);
    }else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to go back to all the items on the stack (not only home) like Youtube, try the following code:

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
FragmentTransaction transaction;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            (new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.action_item1:
                            selectedFragment = ItemOneFragment.newInstance();
                            break;
                        case R.id.action_item2:
                            selectedFragment = ItemTwoFragment.newInstance();
                            break;
                        case R.id.action_item3:
                            selectedFragment = ItemThreeFragment.newInstance();
                            break;
                        case R.id.action_item4:
                            selectedFragment = ItemFourFragment.newInstance();
                            break;
                        case R.id.action_item5:
                            selectedFragment = ItemFiveFragment.newInstance();
                            break;
                    }
                    transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();
                    return true;
                }
            });

    //Manually displaying the first fragment - one time only
    transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, ItemOneFragment.newInstance());
    transaction.commit();

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    if (count == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        int index = ((getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()) -1);
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backEntry = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(index);
        int stackId = backEntry.getId();
        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(stackId).setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: crashing when randomly switching tabs and then press back